2013 Chrysler 200 losing all functions while driving
While driving my car will almost kick back and then the rpm’s will go to zero, I can’t accelerate or hardly use my brakes and the steering will almost lock up. Once it stops and I get it in park if I put it in drive it rolls back. If I turn it off and try to restart it it’ll sputter. I’ll let it sit for about 45 minutes and then it’ll start back up. It’ll do this and then be fine weeks and then do it again. I’ve brought it to a mechanic and they can’t find anything. There are no codes popping up. Any recommendations?


Could you please explain what you mean by "almost kick back"? 2. Does this only happen while driving crazy fast or driving up long, steep hills?


Mechanics can't solve problems when they aren't presented a vehicle with the problem. When you drive to a repair shop, connect a reader to decode any stored errors and diagnose with your descriptions. Not presenting them the exact problem becomes a mystery to anyone since the problem went away and everything is fine.  Intermittent issues require a shop to hold onto the vehicle and test startup and drive but not take any trips longer than 10-20 minutes since you're paying hourly labor rates and shops don't wish to gouge anyone if they find nothing.  An expert in EFI is needed.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm with @FDryer here as it seems they are suggesting there is a fueling issue. I'd lay wager on there being a problem with the fuel pump. Does this happen when the fuel gets low? If so, your fuel pump could be going out and quits pumping when it overheats. Your description seems to point in this direction, but you'd have to monitor the fuel pressure at the time of occurrence to verify.
